# Tableau doesn't shows latest data

Tags: tableau-api

newbie to tableau since 2 weeks
i created dashboard in tableau and it shows schedule

i published dashboard but it does not shows latest data in database

[image]

**so how to show latest data on browser refresh as soon as database is updated ?**

**Note**: *not talking about live data streaming*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days found solution **buried** in tableau documentation

[By Tableau Bridge you can maintain fresh data all the time](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_sync_local_data.htm)

[Tableau Bridge Example Video](https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/tableau-bridge)

To promote their product, Tableau have hidden fresh data documentation deep down, that no one could find

Answer (score 1):

When you use Extract and don't set refresh schedule then you won't be able to see the latest data.

You should keep a Refresh Schedule if you are using an Extract. For example, you can keep a Daily Night Schedule for refresh.

You can check the Last extract status or refresh schedule in server under the specific workbook.

Comment: thanks for reply @akshay is there any way i can reduce the refresh time below 1 hour ...like i want to reach till atleast 5 minutes

Comment: I don't think tableau allows to add customized refresh schedule. If you want data to be refreshed every 5 minutes then use Live instead Extract but the performance of workbook won't be the same for large data.

Comment: when you said ''live'' it will be only during ''tableau desktop'' and for ''tableau online'' ....right ?

Comment: Yes, it'll be for tableau desktop and online

Comment: soory  it wont be available for ''tableau online''

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a data extract then the data will appear on the page after extract has run successfully. Check the schedule status to see if the schedule was  successfully completed. You can manually run the task after creating a schedule for it also.

Comment: I wanted latest data to appear on dashboard refresh , without running schedule , like normal reports we create in html

Comment: So @Kalidas you mean to say without running schedule i will not get latest data on dashboard ?